# Scriptlets in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm reading Head First ROR tutorial. I follow the book - I use scriptlest in my code:

```
<ul> 
  <% for ad in @ads %>
    <li>
      <a href="/ads/<%=ad.id %>">
        <%= ad.name %>
      </a>
    </li>
  <% end %>
</ul>
```

Unfortunately loop doesn't work - on my site I see only title. Book is written about old version of Rails - is it something wrong with the script, something which doesn't work in new ROR?

Comment: Where do you define `@ads`?  Can you post that code please.

Comment: Check your log file for errors.

Comment: def index
    @ads=Ad.all
  end

Comment: Do you have any `Ads` in the database?

Comment: In order to see what's inside `@ads` you can put something like `<li><%= @ads.inspect %></li>` before the `for loop`

Comment: What's the book? do you have a link? What Rails version is it about? What version are you using?

Comment: Yes, book provides database - I put file called "development.sqlite3" in directory db, as the book stated

Comment: It's Head First ROR, I use newest version, and it's written for 2.1

Answer (score 0):

Its probably a break away from the way the book is teaching you, but most Ruby/Rails devs would recommend doing `<% @ads.each do |ad| %>` instead of `<% for ad in @ads %>`

Comment: especially considering that `for x in xx` is implemented in terms of `xx.each { |x| }`.

Comment: Thank you, I will remember in the future. Unfortunately it doesn't help, I think it's something wrong with reading data from database